# Round function php

Tags: php, rounding

Maybe the question is simple, but I can't find the answer.
What I need to do is to round number to 2 places after comma. 
Im using this:

```
round(($data/$count*100), 2)
```

And when I get number like:

```
60.36036036036012 and : 37.83783783783808 is OK, because it's: 60.36 and 37.84
```

But why this:

```
1.8018018018018036
```

Is rounded to this:

```
1.8000000000000003
```

How to round always to 2 places, after comma?

Comment: it rounds to `1.8` for me http://codepad.viper-7.com/bv7ZbD

Answer (score 1):

You should get `1.8` unless you use something like old PHP version with some sort of related bugs. Still, if you want to see `1.80` you need to format output string, otherwise trailing zero will be stripped by default. The most flexible approach would be to use `sprintf()` formatting, like this:

```
$val = 1.8000000000000003;
printf("%.02f", round( $val, 2 ));
```

which would produce

```
1.80
```

The key is "%.02f" which means you want to format (f)loating point value, with two digits after dot, padded with `0` when needed (like this case).

[See the sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf) docs for more about available formatting possibilites.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP NumberFormatter class http://es.php.net/manual/es/class.numberformatter.php